# how to fade-out an alert using effect using vuetify and Vue.delete()

Tags: css, vue.js, css-transitions, vuetify.js, fade

I have a message service that renders a `v-alert` for certain api calls. I want them to fade-in and then fade-out after 5 seconds.

Using Vue's (read: not Vuetify's) [list transition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions) pattern, I can get messages to fade-in, but I can't get them to fade out—they simply disappear.

the part of the template rendering the messages:

```
<v-container v-if="show">
  <transition-group name="fade">
    <div v-for="(message, index) in messageList" :key="index">
      <v-alert>
        {{ message.message }}
      </v-alert>
    </div>
  </transition-group>
</v-container>
```

the styles:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active
  transition: opacity .5s ease

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to
  opacity: 0
```

Messages are added to the message list using Vue.set() and after a setTimeout of 5 seconds, Vue.delete()'d.

```js
// mutations
[SET_MESSAGE](state, payload) {
  Vue.set(state.appMessages, payload.key, payload.message)
},
[DELETE_MESSAGE](state, key) {
  Vue.delete(state.appMessages, key)
}

// actions
[PROCESS_MESSAGE]({ commit }, message) {
  const timestamp = String(new Date().getTime())
  commit(SET_MESSAGE, { key, message })
  setTimeout(() => commit(DELETE_MESSAGE, timestamp), 5000)
}
```

Show is simply a computed property that returns true if there are any elements in the message list array.

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({ messageList }),
  show(): boolean {
    if (!Array.isArray(this.messageList)) {
      return false
    }
    return this.messageList.length > 0
  }
}
```

Any ideas or better ways to go about this? I can get it working with raw css / selectors but I want to try and do it using vue/vuetify.

Comment: Any specific reason why you need to remove those dynamic properties? Also, please show us what this object `show` does or how it is toggled, is it a computed prop?

Comment: @YomS. edited—and I'm not deleting properties I'm deleting elements themselves so that they don't stack up and disappear instead.

Comment: I mean why did you need to `Vue.delete` them? In your use case, this might just deprive the reactivity of the `store.state`. Maybe have a read on array change detection caveat in the docs.